# R: Substring Matching

Tags: r, match

I have a column of characters `names` containing the following:

```
Raymond K
Raymond K-S
Raymond KS
Bill D
Raymond Kerry
Blanche D
Blanche Diamond
Bill Dates
```

I also have a character vector `m_names` containing the following:

```
Raymond K
Blanche D
```

I would like to create a column `outcome` that returns a non-zero integer if there is a matched substring and return 0 if there are no matches. For example, for the column of text above I would ideally like to see an outcome where

```
[1] 1 1 1 0 1 2 2 0
```

Currently, I have tried the following code:

```
outcome <- pmatch(as.character(names), m_names, nomatch = 0)
```

but this only returns the following `outcome`:

```
[1] 1 0 0 0 1 2 0 0
```

How can I ensure that even if there isn't an exact match, the code will still return a value that identifies a partial match in R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#create an empty outcome vector

outcome<-vector(mode="integer",length=length(names))

# loop for the length of compare vector (m_names)
for(i in 1:length(m_names)) {
  outcome[grep(m_names[i],names)]<-i
}
```

Answer (score 4):

A simpler example with some documents and search strings:

```
# Some documents
docs <- c("aab", "aba", "bbaa", "b")

# Some search strings (regular expressions)
searchstr <- c("aa", "ab")
```

1) The number of in the outcome vector shall count the number of matching search strings (1 means "aa" or "ab" matches", 2 means that both match)

```
Reduce('+', lapply(searchstr, grepl, x = docs))
# Returns: [1] 2 1 1 0
```

2) The number of the outcome shall indicate if search string 1 matches or search string 2 matches. Return the highest number if both are matching. (I think, that is what you intended)

```
n <- length(searchstr)
Reduce(pmax, lapply(1:n, function(x) x * grepl(searchstr[x], docs)))
# Returns: [1] 2 2 1 0
```

Now finally we consider your example:

```
docs <- c("Raymond K", "Raymond K", "Raymond KS", "Bill D", 
          "Raymond Kerry", "Blanche D", "Blanche Diamond", 
          "Bill Dates")
searchstr <- c("Raymond K", "Blanche D")
Reduce(pmax, lapply(1:n, function(x) x * grepl(searchstr[x], docs)))
# Returns: [1] 1 1 1 0 1 2 2 0
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do it with `stringi`:

```
library("stringi")    

# data example:

a <- read.table(text="
                Raymond K
                Raymond K-S
                Raymond KS
                Bill D
                Raymond Kerry
                Blanche D
                Blanche Diamond
                Bill Dates", 
                stringsAsFactors=FALSE, sep="\t")

wek <- c("Raymond K", "Blanche D")

# solution

klasa <- numeric(length(a[, 1]))
for(i in 1:length(wek)){
    klasa[stri_detect_fixed(a[, 1], wek[i])] <- i
}
```

Comment: I actually went for stringi and found this extremely helpful! Thank you so much Marta.